# How can I get rid of unwanted empty XML tags?

Tags: sql, xml, oracle

In the below SQL XML I want to not show the `recordingInfo` tag if all these fields are null:

```
cc.source_album_title
cc.product_album_promo_title
cc.label
cc.catalogue_no
cc.isrc
```

This is my current query:

```
 SELECT XMLAGG(XMLElement("Cue"  -- start level 5 tag for cue                                            
                             ,XMLFOREST( rownum as "cueId"    
                             ,cc.dn_ccst_status as "cueStatusType"                                        
                             ,decode(cc.dn_ccst_status,'5',cc.cup_code,NULL) as  "cueCupType" )                                                                                 
                                ,XMLElement("musicWork"  -- start level 6 tag for music title   
                                        ,XMLFOREST(cc.title as "musicTitle") 
                                        ,XMLElement("recordingInfo"  -- start level 7 tag for music title
                                                ,XMLFOREST( cc.source_album_title as "albumTitle"    
                                                            ,cc.product_album_promo_title as "promoTitle"                                        
                                                            ,cc.label as  "label"    
                                                            ,cc.catalogue_no as "catalogNumber"    
                                                            ,cc.isrc as "isrc")                                                                                   
                                                    )     

                                          )  -- end level 6 tag for music title   

                 )  -- end level 5 tag cue
              )
FROM creation_components cc
WHERE cc.prod_cre_surr_id = 22736214
```

This generates XML with both an empty `recordingInfo` tag if the columns listed above are all null:

```
<Cue>
   <cueId>1</cueId>
   <cueStatusType>5</cueStatusType>
   <cueCupType>W</cueCupType>
   <musicWork>
       <musicTitle>CLARE@RADIOWORKS.CO.UK</musicTitle>
       <recordingInfo></recordingInfo>
   </musicWork>
</Cue>
```

How can I stop it including the empty `recordingInfo` tag if there are no other elements generated within it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a nested `XMLForest(.. as "recordingInfo")` call instead of the `XMLElement("recordingInfo")`:

```
SELECT XMLAGG(XMLElement("Cue"  -- start level 5 tag for cue
  ,XMLFOREST( rownum as "cueId"
  ,cc.dn_ccst_status as "cueStatusType"
  ,decode(cc.dn_ccst_status,'5',cc.cup_code,NULL) as  "cueCupType" )
  ,XMLElement("musicWork"  -- start level 6 tag for music title
    ,XMLFOREST(cc.title as "musicTitle")
    ,XMLFOREST(
      XMLFOREST(cc.source_album_title as "albumTitle"
        ,cc.product_album_promo_title as "promoTitle"
        ,cc.label as  "label"
        ,cc.catalogue_no as "catalogNumber"
        ,cc.isrc as "isrc") as "recordingInfo"  -- start level 7 tag for music title
      )
    )  -- end level 6 tag for music title
  )  -- end level 5 tag cue
)
FROM creation_components cc
WHERE cc.prod_cre_surr_id = 22736214;
```

With dummy data to match your sample output, and an `XMLSerialise` wrapper to prettify the output:

```
WITH creation_components (prod_cre_surr_id, dn_ccst_status, cup_code, title,
  source_album_title, product_album_promo_title, label, catalogue_no, isrc) as
(
  SELECT 22736214, 5, 'W', 'CLARE@RADIOWORKS.CO.UK',
    null, null, null, null, null from dual
)
SELECT XMLSERIALIZE(Document
  XMLAGG(XMLElement("Cue"  -- start level 5 tag for cue
    ,XMLFOREST( rownum as "cueId"
    ,cc.dn_ccst_status as "cueStatusType"
    ,decode(cc.dn_ccst_status,'5',cc.cup_code,NULL) as  "cueCupType" )
    ,XMLElement("musicWork"  -- start level 6 tag for music title
      ,XMLFOREST(cc.title as "musicTitle")
      ,XMLFOREST(
        XMLFOREST(cc.source_album_title as "albumTitle"
          ,cc.product_album_promo_title as "promoTitle"
          ,cc.label as  "label"
          ,cc.catalogue_no as "catalogNumber"
          ,cc.isrc as "isrc") as "recordingInfo"  -- start level 7 tag for music title
        )
      )  -- end level 6 tag for music title 
    )  -- end level 5 tag cue
  )
  as CLOB INDENT SIZE = 2
)
FROM creation_components cc
WHERE cc.prod_cre_surr_id = 22736214;
```

gets

```
XMLSERIALIZE(DOCUMENTXMLAGG(XMLELEMENT("CUE"--STARTLEVEL5TAGFORCUE,XMLFOREST(ROW
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
<Cue>
  <cueId>1</cueId>
  <cueStatusType>5</cueStatusType>
  <cueCupType>W</cueCupType>
  <musicWork>
    <musicTitle>CLARE@RADIOWORKS.CO.UK</musicTitle>
  </musicWork>
</Cue>
```

With non-null data in the later columns:

```
WITH creation_components (prod_cre_surr_id, dn_ccst_status, cup_code, title,
  source_album_title, product_album_promo_title, label, catalogue_no, isrc) as
(
  SELECT 22736214, 5, 'W', 'CLARE@RADIOWORKS.CO.UK',
    null, null, 'RadioWorks', null, null from dual
)
SELECT XMLSERIALIZE(Document
  XMLAGG(XMLElement("Cue"  -- start level 5 tag for cue
    ,XMLFOREST( rownum as "cueId"
    ,cc.dn_ccst_status as "cueStatusType"
    ,decode(cc.dn_ccst_status,'5',cc.cup_code,NULL) as  "cueCupType" )
    ,XMLElement("musicWork"  -- start level 6 tag for music title
      ,XMLFOREST(cc.title as "musicTitle")
      ,XMLFOREST(
        XMLFOREST(cc.source_album_title as "albumTitle"
          ,cc.product_album_promo_title as "promoTitle"
          ,cc.label as  "label"
          ,cc.catalogue_no as "catalogNumber"
          ,cc.isrc as "isrc") as "recordingInfo"  -- start level 7 tag for music title
        )
      )  -- end level 6 tag for music title
    )  -- end level 5 tag cue
  )
  as CLOB INDENT SIZE = 2
)
FROM creation_components cc
WHERE cc.prod_cre_surr_id = 22736214;
```

the extra tag still appears:

```
XMLSERIALIZE(DOCUMENTXMLAGG(XMLELEMENT("CUE"--STARTLEVEL5TAGFORCUE,XMLFOREST(ROW
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
<Cue>
  <cueId>1</cueId>
  <cueStatusType>5</cueStatusType>
  <cueCupType>W</cueCupType>
  <musicWork>
    <musicTitle>CLARE@RADIOWORKS.CO.UK</musicTitle>
    <recordingInfo>
      <label>RadioWorks</label>
    </recordingInfo>
  </musicWork>
</Cue>
```

Comment: Correct again Alex Poole you are truley the expert on XML SQL.. thank you so much for all your help, it worked first time with it enclosed in an extra XMLFOREST