# Delete Empty tag from xmltype oracle

Tags: sql, xml, oracle

i want try to delete the empty tag from xmltype. I Have generate the below xml from oracle type. In the collection few elements does not have values so i generated with empty tag.

Can any one please help me out:

Actual output:

```
<MESSAGE>
<LOCATIONS>
  <LOCATION_ID>9999</LOCATION_ID>
  <LOC_TYPE>S</LOC_TYPE>
  <NAME>Test Location</NAME> 
  <PHONE_NUM>08 </PHONE_NUM>
   <LAST_MODIFIED_BY/>
   <LAST_MODIFIED_DATE/>
   <POS_CODE/>
</LOCATIONS>
</MESSAGE>
```

Expected output:

```
<MESSAGE>
<LOCATIONS>
  <LOCATION_ID>9999</LOCATION_ID>
  <LOC_TYPE>S</LOC_TYPE>
  <NAME>Test Location</NAME> 
  <PHONE_NUM>08 </PHONE_NUM>
</LOCATIONS>
</MESSAGE>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I get rid of unwanted empty XML tags?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36340104/how-can-i-get-rid-of-unwanted-empty-xml-tags)

Comment: @KaushikNayak Not a duplicate - the one you have linked is trying to generate the XMLType without including the empty XML tags whereas this one the XMLType already exists containing empty XML tags that need removing.

Answer (score 2):

Use `DELETEXML` and look for the XPath `//*[not(text())][not(*)]` to find elements that contain no text and no children:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e2f47/15)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name ( xml ) AS
SELECT XMLTYPE( '<MESSAGE>
<LOCATIONS>
  <LOCATION_ID>9999</LOCATION_ID>
  <LOC_TYPE>S</LOC_TYPE>
  <NAME>Test Location</NAME> 
  <PHONE_NUM>08 </PHONE_NUM>
   <LAST_MODIFIED_BY/>
   <LAST_MODIFIED_DATE/>
   <POS_CODE/>
</LOCATIONS>
</MESSAGE>' ) FROM DUAL;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT DELETEXML(
         xml,
         '//*[not(text())][not(*)]'
       ).getStringVal()
FROM   table_name
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e2f47/15/0)**:

```
|                                                                                            DELETEXML(XML,'//*[NOT(TEXT())][NOT(*)]').GETSTRINGVAL() |
|-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
| <MESSAGE><LOCATIONS><LOCATION_ID>9999</LOCATION_ID><LOC_TYPE>S</LOC_TYPE><NAME>Test Location</NAME><PHONE_NUM>08 </PHONE_NUM></LOCATIONS></MESSAGE> |
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    SELECT
        deletexml(xml_data, '//*[not(text())][not(*)]').getstringval()
    FROM
        (
            SELECT
                xmltype('<MESSAGE>
    <LOCATIONS>
      <LOCATION_ID>9999</LOCATION_ID>
      <LOC_TYPE>S</LOC_TYPE>
      <NAME>Test Location</NAME> 
      <PHONE_NUM>08 </PHONE_NUM>
       <LAST_MODIFIED_BY/>
       <LAST_MODIFIED_DATE/>
       <POS_CODE/>
    </LOCATIONS>
    </MESSAGE>'
                ) xml_data
            FROM
                dual
        )
```

this is working fine thanks